# Force cp to perform illegal operation on inode

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I'm attempting to create custom FUSE "*filesystem*" with non-standard behavior (not meant for conventional file storage) and I wonder if there's a way to force cp to perform illegal operation on file?

By illegal operation i specifically mean `clone`, `link` or `unlink` on non-empty directory (not file). If not then I guess I could just write own equivalent of cp but I'd always be better to use standard, widely available tools.

Comment: Aren't you the one defining the FS?  Then if you plan it correctly, you could have it behave any way you want.  You appear to assume that the way another filesystem operates is the good way and yours would do illegal operations but that is not the way to face it.  Finally, note that it's a rather complex programming challenge to define your own FS and it is completely off-topic here.

Comment: I know it's not illegal for me. What i meant is that cp shows messages like `omitting directory`. I'm not sure if it even attempts to issue operation on file. I think it just assumes it's wrong and skips it without even trying.

Comment: `omitting directory` is indeed a message from `cp` that you try to copy a directory as if it were a regular file.  No matter what filesystem you use, you will need to put certain logical organizational rules like files and directory structure.  Otherwise you'd be going back 40 years or more back in time.  But the restrictions that stop you from deleting a non empty directory are not implemented in the user tools but at a lower level where the actual check is made.  I'm not sure I'd want to work on a system that allows deleting a directory which is in use or includes other files though.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can coax `cp` into unlinking anything, but there's an [unlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unlink.1.html) command that will do that.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick:  My comment was more general about OP's new FS than just `cp`.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Oh, I was just referring to the OP's question. I think the testing with unusual file operations can be done, just not by using various arguments to `cp` as the OP requests.